# HTML/JS- Table formatting when populating fields with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Still learning HTTP formatting, so please bear with me.
This page takes a first name, and displays all people with the same first name.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
        var myObj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
        console.log(myObj);
        txt += "<table border='1'>"
         for (x in myObj) {
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].friend_id + "</td></tr>";
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].birth_date + "</td></tr>";
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].first_name + "</td></tr>";
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].last_name + "</td></tr>";
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].gender + "</td></tr>";
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].phone+ "</td></tr>";
        }
        txt += "</table>" 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

    }
}
```

This is my code- I sent a HTTP request, take the Response, (which contains JSON) and print that to the page.

JSON- https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6GxA.jpg

However, this is what my page looks like when I try to display the JSON code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ZLt.jpg

How can I change this? Im still learning formatting, so Im not sure how to fix this when populating stuff from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new row (`<tr>`) for each value.
Instead you should create a row once for every entry.

```
for (x in myObj) {
    txt += "<tr>"
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].friend_id + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].birth_date + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].first_name + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].last_name + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].gender + "</td>";
    txt += "<td>" + myObj[x].phone+ "</td>";
    txt += "</tr>"
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Manuel Otto! I just had 1 more question- If I wanted to add a header for the top of the table, how would I do that? Would it be HTML code about the for loop?

Comment: @HahaHaha yes, you'd have to add that right above the for loop after `txt += "<table border='1'>"`.